# Laravel Echo not receiving puher events

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

My events are receiving at the pusher like-

Event - **API message**

Details - **Channel: private-chat, Event: App\Events\MessageSent**

But in my Vue frontend, Echo is not receiving any events from pusher.

MessageSent.php

```
class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, Message $message)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat');
    }
}
```

chat.vue

```
  mounted() {
    Echo.private("chat").listen("MessageSent", (e) => {
      console.log("Received");
      this.allMessages.push(e.message);
      this.fetchMessages();
    });
  },
```

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
});
```

routes/channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return auth()->check();
});
```

I have also set up broadcast driver = pusher & all the pusher credentials in my .env file

Comment: Have you added authorization logic in `routes\channels.php`?

Comment: Did you see any error in your dev tool?

Comment: There is no error.

Answer (score 0):

In MessageSent event do this

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
    return new PrivateChannel('chat');
}
```

And in BroadcastServiceProvider add the following line:

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

Comment: But the vue frontend is not a separate app. It's inside the laravel. So I am not using any api routes here.

Comment: If you are using Laravel Auth include it in your private channel. Otherwise include other middleware you are using for user authentication.
Private channel requires a middleware, else it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by putting the below code from bootstrap.js to app.js. So, in my app.js -

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
});
```

But I don't know why the same code is not working in bootstrap.js